# Rock–paper–scissors console game

Tags: c++, beginner, game, rock-paper-scissors

I wrote this console rock-paper-scissors game. I'm new to C++. I'd appreciate any suggestions to improve the code below. Thanks.

**RPSCore.h**

```
#ifndef RPS_CORE_H
#define RPS_CORE_H


class RPSCore
{
public:
    static int rpsWinner(char& playerChoice, char& computerChoice);
    static char getComputerChoice();
};

#endif // !RPS_CORE_H
```

**RPSCore.cc**

```
#include <random>
#include <chrono>
#include <cstdint>
#include <map>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>

#include "RPSCore.h"

// private helper function
char getValueIfKeyExists(std::map<std::string, char>& dict, std::string& key)
{
    char ret = '\0';
    for (std::map<std::string, char>::iterator it = dict.begin(); it != dict.end(); it++)
    {
        if (it->first.compare(key) == 0)
        {
            ret = it->second;
            break;
        }
    }
    return ret;
}

int RPSCore::rpsWinner(char& playerChoice, char& computerChoice)
{
    std::map<std::string, char> rules = { {"rs", 'r'}, {"rp", 'p'}, {"sp", 's'} };
    std::stringstream ss;
    ss << playerChoice << computerChoice;
    std::string combination = ss.str();
    std::string combinationCopy{ combination };
    std::reverse(combinationCopy.begin(), combinationCopy.end());
    char p = getValueIfKeyExists(rules, combination) == '\0' ? getValueIfKeyExists(rules, combinationCopy) : getValueIfKeyExists(rules, combination);
    return p == playerChoice && p != computerChoice ? 1 : p == computerChoice && p != playerChoice ? 2 : -1; // 1-> player wins, 2-> computer wins, -1-> draw
}

char RPSCore::getComputerChoice()
{
    std::string options = "rps";
    uint32_t seed = static_cast<uint32_t>(std::chrono::system_clock::now().time_since_epoch().count());
    std::minstd_rand0 range(seed);
    std::uniform_int_distribution<std::minstd_rand0::result_type> dist(0, 2);
    return options[dist(range)];    
}
```

**main.cc**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cctype>

#include "RPSCore.h"

std::string input(std::string prompt="")
{
    std::string temp;
    std::cout << prompt;
    std::getline(std::cin, temp);
    return temp;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    char playerChoice = []() {
        std::string ret = "";
        do
        {
            ret = input("Your weapon >>> ");
            if (std::tolower(ret[0]) == 'r' || std::tolower(ret[0]) == 'p' || std::tolower(ret[0]) == 's') break;
        } while (1);
        return ret[0];
    }();
    char computerChoice = RPSCore::getComputerChoice();
    int winner = RPSCore::rpsWinner(playerChoice, computerChoice);
    std::cout << "Your choice: " << (playerChoice == 'r' ? "Rock" : playerChoice == 'p' ? "Paper" : "Scissors")  << " Computer's choice: " << (computerChoice == 'r' ? "Rock" : computerChoice == 'p' ? "Paper" : "Scissors") << " And " << (winner == 1 ? "You WIN!!!" : winner == 2 ? "Computer Wins :(" : "It's a draw :)");
    std::cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Where is my Lizard/Spock? https://iwastesomuchtime.com/21448

Answer (score 1):

I'm thinking you named `ret` as in short for `return`.
Don't shorten variable names. Also try to give varaible names that are meaningful. Naming it return because you return it is silly.

```
char ret = '\0';
```

Same here:

```
std::string temp;
```

This line looks very odd and is a sign of poorly named variables:

```
ret = it->second;
```

`r`, `p` `s` these are a good example of when you should be using an ENUM.

Try to avoid 1 letter variable names.

You can use `const` when variables should never change. For example: `rules`.

I suggest putting the condition inside the while instead.
For example:

```
} while (std::tolower(ret[0]) != 'r' || std::tolower(ret[0]) != 'p' || std::tolower(ret[0]) != 's');
```

If you had an ENUM, you could check the entered value against all the values in the ENUM. This would look much better, and be easier to maintain. (E.g adding `Lizard` `Spock`)

The ENUM would also help for printing the values. (No more if `r` print `rock` etc)

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand why you would do this:

```
char playerChoice = []() {
    std::string ret = "";
    do
    {
        ret = input("Your weapon >>> ");
        if (std::tolower(ret[0]) == 'r' || std::tolower(ret[0]) == 'p' || std::tolower(ret[0]) == 's') break;
    } while (1);
    return ret[0];
}();
```

Creating an inline function and calling it!

That could should be in its own named function.

```
char getPlayerChoice()
{
    std::string ret = "";
    do
    {
        ret = input("Your weapon >>> ");
        if (std::tolower(ret[0]) == 'r' || std::tolower(ret[0]) == 'p' || std::tolower(ret[0]) == 's') break;
    } while (1);
    return ret[0];
}
```

Then simply call it like normal.

```
char playerChoice = getPlayerChoice();
```

---

This line is excessively long:

```
std::cout << "Your choice: " << (playerChoice == 'r' ? "Rock" : playerChoice == 'p' ? "Paper" : "Scissors")  << " Computer's choice: " << (computerChoice == 'r' ? "Rock" : computerChoice == 'p' ? "Paper" : "Scissors") << " And " << (winner == 1 ? "You WIN!!!" : winner == 2 ? "Computer Wins :(" : "It's a draw :)");
```

Make it readable:

```
std::cout << "Your choice: "
          << (playerChoice == 'r' ? "Rock" : playerChoice == 'p' ? "Paper" : "Scissors")
          << " Computer's choice: "
          << (computerChoice == 'r' ? "Rock" : computerChoice == 'p' ? "Paper" : "Scissors")
          << " And "
          << (winner == 1
                  ? "You WIN!!!" 
                  : winner == 2 
                        ? "Computer Wins 
                        :(" : "It's a draw :)");
```

Would be even better if you used some named functions:

```
std::cout << "Your choice: " << choiceToOutput(playerChoice)
          << " Computer's choice: " << choiceToOutput(computerChoice)
          << " And " << winnerToOutput(winner)
          << "\n";
```

---

Are you trying to draw smiley faces in the code:

```
 :(" : "It's a draw :)");
```

Fun. But stop it.

```
 : " : "It's a draw :)";
```

Comment: Practicing Immediately Invoked Initializing Lambda, perhaps?